# How Do I Construct my Ember Models and API Data to represent data on the relationship?

Tags: ember.js, json-api

I'm new to jsonapi and how the structure works and trying to get a relationship to load properly. I'm expecting ember-data to follow provided url's in the relationship.links of my objects to fetch the required information but I'm getting unexpected results.

I have Users, Territories, and a User/Territory relationship defined like this:

```
// User Model
const UserModel = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    territories: DS.hasMany('user-territories')
}

// Territory Model
const TerritoryModel = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
}

// User-Territory Model
const UserTerritoryModel = DS.Model.extend({
    notes: DS.attr('string'),
    startDate: DS.attr('date'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    territory: DS.belongsTo('territory')
}
```

I then have mock data (using http-mock) that looks like this:

```
// api/users/
data: {
    type: "users",
    id: 1,
    attributes: {
        username: "thisIsMyUsername"
    }
},
relationships: {
    territories: {
        links: {
            self: "http://localhost:4200/api/users/1/territories"
        }
    }
}

// api/users/1/territories
data: {
    type: "user-territories",
    id: 1,
    attributes: {
        notes: "This is a note",
        startDate: "2017-01-01"
    }
},
relationships: {
    user: {
        link: {
            self: "http://localhost:4200/api/users/1"
        }
    },
    territory: {
        link: {
            self: "http://localhost:4200/api/territories/1"
        }
    }
}

// api/territories/1
data: {
    type: "territories",
    id: 1,
    attributes: {
        name: "Territory #1"
    }
}
```

In my User route, I want to request the UserModel and have access to the UserTerritory Relationship data and the Territory itself. The api calls are not what I expect though:

```
this.get('store').findRecord('user', 1, { include: "territories" });
```

EXPECTED:

- api/users/1
- api/users/1/territories

ACTUAL:

- api/users/1
- api/users/1?include=territories

If I call the user-territories model I get this:

EXPECTED:

- api/users/1/territories

ACTUAL:

- api/user-territories/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `included`, ember-data basically thinks you want to tell the server to side-load data. If you return a `links`, just resolve the relationship. However the `relationships` have to be inside the `data`. Also the `self` link is for the relationship itself, to return the data use `related`.

So first you do something like `user = store.findRecord('user', '1')`, this will fetch to `api/users/`. Then you should return something like this:

```
// api/users/
{
  data: {
    type: "users",
    id: 1,
    attributes: {
      username: "thisIsMyUsername"
    }
    relationships: {
      territories: {
        links: {
          related: "http://localhost:4200/api/users/1/territories"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next you do `user.get('territories')`. This will return a promise, and fetch `http://localhost:4200/api/users/1/territories`, or whatever was inside that related link. However know, what `ember-data` will expect you to return `user-territories` here, because thats what you specified with `territories: DS.hasMany('user-territories')`. You should know what you directly can model an many-to-many relationship in `ember-data` without a third table.